# R select rows meet at least 2 out of the 5 criteria

Tags: r

How do I select people who met at least 2 of 5 criteria? ID is patient IDs and C1-5 are the 5 criteria. ID 1, 4 and 5 met at least 2 of the 5 criteria and I need to pick them out.

```
ID <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
C1 <- c(1,0,0,1,1)
C2 <- c(0,0,0,1,1)
C3 <- c(0,0,0,0,0)
C4 <- c(0,0,0,0,1)
C5 <- c(1,0,0,0,0)
df <- data.frame(ID, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `rowSums` to get the sum of each row (of the appropriate columns) and see which rows have a sum `>=2`.

```
df[rowSums(df[-1]) >= 2, ]
```

If you like `dplyr`, you could do it like this:

```
library(dplyr)
df |> filter(rowSums(across(starts_with("C"))) >= 2)
```